# Duplication with List <T> C#

Tags: c#, list

I have some issues with a list. My list have properties (Location, Time, Activities). I have used `thelist.GroupBy(f => new { f.Place, f.Time, f.Name}).Select(c => c.First())`. But, I am still getting duplicate. My `outComelist` looks like:

```
Paris 2013-09-12 John
New York 2015-12-10 Lian
Paris 2013-09-12 John
Cape Town 2014-08-21 Peter
Tokyo 2015-12-12 Bob
Paris 2015-09-12-Lean
```

I want my list that should look:

```
Paris 2013-09-12 John
New York 2015-12-10 Lian
Cape Town 2014-08-21 Peter
Tokyo 2015-12-12 Bob
Paris 2015-09-12-Lean
```

Comment: What is the DataType of `Time` ? Is is a String or a `DateTime` object ?

Comment: Note that calling `GroupBy` and then `Select` returns an enumerator for the resulting collection but **does not** modify the original `thelist` list.

Comment: There must be something in your code you're not telling us, because it should work: http://rextester.com/UCT62601

I think fixagon might be right (or you're not persisting your new collection, as @Grx70 mentions).

Comment: @decPL didnt know rextester, nice

Comment: Time is DataTime.

Comment: @fixagon me neither :P first google result for `C# online` (knew a few alternatives, but couldn't remember the addresses; can't really said if this one's better or worse - it did the job here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `f.Time` object is of type `DateTime` with same date but not exact same time in multiple entries.
You can have the grouping over the desired combination by using:

```
thelist.GroupBy(f => new { f.Place, f.Time.Date, f.Name}).Select(c => c.First())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct`

```
thelist.DistinctBy(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: This does something completely different than the grouping in the question

Comment: @fixagon It's not a complete solution, but you can group by the distinct items afterwards.

Comment: But thats not what (it looks like) OP wants: He wants a list of unique combinations of date, place and name. Not a list which is just unique by name